Concatenating static and dynamic strings in Power Query File.Contents function
I'm importing a PDF file into Power Query and parsing as necessary. The source folder name is static, but the file name itself can change.
What I'm trying to do is build a File.Contents() statement in Power Query that concatenates the static folder name with a variable that stores the file name...something like this:
Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents("C:\MyFolderPath" & myfilename), [Implementation="1.3"])
where myfilename = "myfile.pdf"
The user will then copy and paste the filename into a table on a worksheet and refresh the query to generate the parsed output.
How do I structure things so that...
File.Contents("C:\MyFolderPath" & myfilename)
properly renders as...
File.Contents("C:\MyFolderPath\myfile.pdf")
and extracts the contents of the file for parsing?
Note that I have two queries in play...one that imports/parses the PDF and another that contains just the filename (generated from the table on the worksheet).
I plan to improve the process later to make it less "clunky" but for now I just need to know how to do it as described. This is a very simple/basic thing to do in Power Query and I need to know how it's done.
Thank you in advance.

File.Contents("C:\MyFolderPath" & myfilename) should work perfectly
